# If condition for Values in Map<string,List<string>in apex

Tags: apex, map, code, if

I have below snapshot where i just wanted to check if map is having the value 20 in it or not.
How i can write if condition for list of string values

```
map<string,List<string>> getmap=new map<string,list<string>>();
                list<string> getList = new list<string>();
```

Comment: please explain a bit more about your problem. do you want to find 20 in the key or in the list, Whether 20 can be contained inside an String or a String value has to be compared to be equal to 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the map and check the list to search like this:

```
for (String key: getmap.keySet()) {
    if (getmap.get(key).contains('20')) {
        //20 found, do something
    }
}
```